# Unexpected character in input: '\'

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to launch a php script from a cron job in Bluehost.

When I access the script manually it perfectly woks, but when triggered by the cron job it gives the following error:

```
[17-Jul-2013 08:36:01] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home2/XXXXX/public_html/XXXXX/reblog.php on line 17
[17-Jul-2013 08:36:01] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home2/XXXXX/public_html/XXXXX/reblog.php on line 17
```

Line 1 is the following:

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
```

I have the feeling cron job uses a different version of PHP, which is generally set as 5.4.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's not expecting backslashes there you are running on 5.2.x or lower. Run a script that just contains `trigger_error('PHP Version is ' . php_version(), E_USER_ERROR);` to establish which.

Comment: '[17-Jul-2013 08:49:01] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  php_version() in...' :(

Comment: Apologies, that should be [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/phpversion) (no underscore)

Comment: Ok, "PHP Version is 5.2.17"

Comment: Right, well you're kind of screwed unless you can find a way to use 5.3.0 or greater - namespaces simply weren't supported before this. Your only other option would be to refactor the entire codebase so it doesn't use namespaces (or closures, another 5.3 feature). It's possible that the server has more than one verion of PHP available, instead of specifying `/usr/bin/php` in the cron job you'd specify `/etc/php5.4/php` (or whatever). But you'll need to contact the server admin to ask whether or not that is is possible - and if it isn't possible, you need a better host. Even 5.3.x is now EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably cli php version 5.4 available, ask Bluehost for the full path and use it.

Comment: Thanks, so now the question becomes: "what is Bluehost full path for PHP 5.4 or above"

Comment: do you have access to ssh? Then find / -name php

Comment: I found the path: /ramdisk/php/54/bin/php5 Thanks for the help

Comment: I was having the same problem. My Bluehost wasn't recognizing namespaces through cron jobs. Used your path in the cron job, and my errors went away. Thank you!